# Use the Find function in VBA to find the first value above the active cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the row number of the result of a find function, I am using the following.

```
Set FindRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":n" & Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(XlUP).Row).Find(What:="Assembly", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

Msgbox (FindRow.Row)
```

This works fine but returns the last cell in the range that has the value in it. 
If I alter the Search Direction to XlNext, this returns the next cell below with the value in it. 
I would like it to search above the active cell for the next value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just need to specify the After parameter. Edit - on reflection depending on active cell the range you are searching could be any size so you need to explain what you mean by "above the active cell".

```
Sub x()

Dim FindRow As Range, r As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")
    Set r = .Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set FindRow = r.Find(What:="Assembly", after:=r(r.Cells.Count), SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End With

If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then MsgBox (FindRow.Row)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the range above the activecell will vary due to the nature of the excel sheet. I have a loop going through each cell in a column and running the above. I would like to use the find function to search above the active cell in bottom to top order. For example: if the active cell was n31, it would search n30-n1 for a specific value, starting with n30. Thanks

Comment: EDIT: I have tried your answer but it returns the last time the value appears below the active cell not the first time it appears above the active cell.

Comment: You said you want to "search above the active cell for the next value". Is the range being seached always a single column?

Comment: yes it is always in the same column. Instead of after:=ActiveCell is there something that will do before:= ActiveCell?

Comment: I have amended the code above. I would advise against using ActiveCell. If the code doesn't work, please post the rest of yours as it may have a bearing on this question.

Comment: This now brings up the next cell below the active cell that has the value in it. I want it to do this but search above the active cell. I could insert my code in but it is lengthy and would only confuse matters. Is there something that looks before the active cell not after?

Comment: Let's say your active cell is N10 and you have data in column A down to row 20. Then your search range is N10:N20. Agreed? If you want to search above N10 you have to redefine your search range. If your active cell is N30 then your search range is N20:N30 and the code above should work.

Comment: That's perfect Thanks